# How to add an open source library to CLion in a Mac?

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide, cjson

I want to use ([cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON)) library in my c++ code. How do I download and add this library to my CLion project in order to import it into my code like this

`#include <cJSON.h>`

This is my cMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(a_star_search)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(a_star_search main.cpp)
```

Comment: Your question should be tagged `cmake`

Answer (score 1):

cJSON is a single file of C, and a single header file. It's enough an add `include_directories(<path_to_cjson_directory>)`

Or if you are have dynamic library of cJSON you will need to use `target_link_libraries(<target_name> cjson)`